# How do I handle non-latin characters (i.e. С крыш наших домов) in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I'm using the `mysql-connector-python` library to connect and write to a MySQL 5.7 db. I've set the encoding to `utf8mb4` with `cursor.execute('SET CHARACTERS SET utf8mb4')`, and even included it in my connect settings:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

sg_titles_db_settings = {
    'user': <user>,
    'password': <password>,
    'host': <host>,
    'port': <port>,
    'database': <db>,
    'charset': 'utf8'
}

def get_mysql_connection():
    try:
        db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(**sg_titles_db_settings)
        return db_connection
    except Error as e:
        print("Error: ", e)
        return False
```

But any non-latin (non-english letters), such as any eastern european alpha character or special symbols (`♬` for example), is inserted as `?`.

Here's the error I receive if I don't change the encoding:

```
1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x9E\xD1\x82\xD0\xB2...' for column...
```

I don't understand what I need to do in order to resolve this issue. Every article I stumble upon doesn't seem to help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the table must also have the utf8 character set or the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MySQL server run this command `SET character_set_results=utf8;`, that should fix it. However, closing the server may not persist that change.

I'm working with docker and it does not persist. The only way to persist the encoding change is to include it in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
    <db name>:
        environment:
            LANG: C.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

That's strange that it's not working for you. I have a project where cyrillic worked for me and I had something roughly like:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='', user='', passwd='', db='', use_unicode=True)
cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute('SET NAMES utf8mb4')
cur.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4")
cur.execute("SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4")

# Actual database stuff goes here

db.commit()

cur.close()
db.close()
```

I notice you are using a different module than the one I typically use. Have you tried other mysql modules like MySQLdb?

Comment: Maybe I'll try a different module